# Register Google GCM by using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I want to change from AsyncTask to RxJava after go through around the web and RxDoc, I cound not found any solution about. Anyone has any idea?

```
 public void getRegId(){
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
                    Log.i("GCM",  msg);

                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                etRegId.setText(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example showing how to wrap your method with RxJava:

```
    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<String>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<String> call() {
            String msg = doSomeWork();
            return Observable.just(msg);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {}

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {}

                @Override
                public void onNext(String msg) {
                    etRegId.setText(msg + "\n");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RxGcm](https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/RxGcm).

It’s a wrapper for Google Cloud Messaging to get rid of services configuration, handling foreground and background notifications depending on application state.

After some setup, you can register the device as follows:

```
    RxGcm.Notifications.register(context)
            .subscribe((token) -> //send to your server?);
```

I hope you find it usefull.

Comment: Actually I'm using it and its kind of awesome!