# Converting this AsyncTask to RxAndroid?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java, rx-android

Bit new to Rx, so am looking for some help on converting the following `AsyncTask` to Rx, hopefully so I can visualize Rx a bit more with code that I already know that does something. I've found a few other SO answers that were somewhat relevant, but alot of them werent network requests and many used different operators for different answers, so am a bit confused.

Heres the `AsyncTask`:

```
public class BackgroundStuff extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        UserAgent myUserAgent = UserAgent.of("xxx:xxxx:xxx");

        RedditClient redditClient = new RedditClient(myUserAgent);
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.userlessApp("xxxxxxxx", UUID.randomUUID());
        OAuthData authData = null;
        try {
            authData = redditClient.getOAuthHelper().easyAuth(credentials);
            redditClient.authenticate(authData);
        } catch (OAuthException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SubredditPaginator sp = new SubredditPaginator(redditClient);

        sp.setLimit(7);
        sp.setSorting(Sorting.HOT);
        sp.setTimePeriod(TimePeriod.DAY);

        sp.setSubreddit("pics");

        sp.next(true);
        Listing<Submission> list = sp.getCurrentListing();

        Submission sub = list.get(1);
        for (Submission submission : list) {
            Log.d("test", "title: " + submission.getTitle());
        }
        Submission sub2 = redditClient.getSubmission(sub.getId());
        System.out.println(sub2.getComments().get(0).getComment().getBody());


        return null;
    }
}
```

For reference, this authenticates to Reddit and then grabs some results from a particular subreddit.

I know I need an `Observable`, and then `.suscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` and `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`, but am not sure how to make the observable.

Comment: Here is my answer for similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738038/register-google-gcm-by-using-rxjava/34738400#34738400

Comment: @ReyPham in your example, where would my network requests go? Also, where is the `Observer` in your answer? I know `.subscribe()` should accept an `Observer` as a parameter, so what does `new Subscriber<String>()` do in that situation?

Comment: In my example, all your works should be implemented in `doSomeWork()` method (in your case is your network request). The result of this method will be emitted later by `Observable.just(msg)`  and then be consumed by a Subscriber<String>. And Subscriber also is an Observer.

Comment: Ok, I got something running. So in your example, `doSomeWork()` returns a String which is stored in `msg`, which that Observable emits. Say I just wanted to run all my stuff without returning anything or doing anything with the data? Is there a short way to do that?

Comment: You can just emit a null object or anything you want. But be sure to subscribe your Observable or else the wrapped code will not run.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in function:

```
    Void doSomething(){
    UserAgent myUserAgent = UserAgent.of("xxx:xxxx:xxx");

    RedditClient redditClient = new RedditClient(myUserAgent);
    Credentials credentials = Credentials.userlessApp("xxxxxxxx", UUID.randomUUID());
    OAuthData authData = null;
    try {
        authData = redditClient.getOAuthHelper().easyAuth(credentials);
        redditClient.authenticate(authData);
    } catch (OAuthException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SubredditPaginator sp = new SubredditPaginator(redditClient);

    sp.setLimit(7);
    sp.setSorting(Sorting.HOT);
    sp.setTimePeriod(TimePeriod.DAY);

    sp.setSubreddit("pics");

    sp.next(true);
    Listing<Submission> list = sp.getCurrentListing();

    Submission sub = list.get(1);
    for (Submission submission : list) {
        Log.d("test", "title: " + submission.getTitle());
    }
    Submission sub2 = redditClient.getSubmission(sub.getId());
    System.out.println(sub2.getComments().get(0).getComment().getBody());


    return null;
    }
```

Wrap it in an observable:

```
Observable.just(doSomething);
```

Wrap it in a defer so it will run only when someone subscribes to it:

```
Observable<Void> doSomethingObservable = Observable.defer(()-> Observable.just(doSomething))
```

Decide where it will run with subscribeOn and observeOn, and subscribe to it to make it run:

```
doSomethingObservable
.suscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe();
```